# Trying to transform a Laravel only project into a Vue + Laravel project. Vue component not mounting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-7

I want to transform an existing Laravel project into a Vue + Laravel Project. I have successfully created a Vue component as a test in the application, so I know that vue was installed correctly.

First, I created a route at web.php file:

```
Route::view('/homepageVue', 'layouts.homepage');
```

Then, I created the layouts.homepage blade file:

```
@extends('lib.master.main')

@section('styles')
@stop

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{!! asset('js/homepage/homepage.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
@stop

@section('title')
    - Homepage
@stop

@section('content')
    <div id="homepage"></div>
@stop
```

Then, I created in the assets folder, the component, and the homepage.js files:

assets/js/homepage/homepage.js:

```
// *****************************
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************
/**
 * Save this instance
 * @type @this;
 * @private
 */
 var self = this;

 /**
  * If Module has been initiated
  * @type Boolean
  * @private
  */
 var _isInit = false; // to avoid 'rebinds'

 /**
  * Categories Component instance
  */
 const homepage = require('./components/homepage');


 // ****************************
 // ***** Public functions *****
 // ****************************
 /**
  * start
  *
  * Starts the module
  * Inits private variables and executes specific logic needed for the module
  * to start.
  *
  * @public
  */
 this.start = function() {
     if(!_isInit) {
         console.log("Homepage starts..");

         homepage.start();
     }
 };

 self.start();
```

Then, I created the assets/js/homepage/component/homepage.js file:

```
// *****************************
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************
/**
 * Save this instance
 * @type @this;
 * @private
 */
 var self = this;

 /**
  * If Module has been initiated
  * @type Boolean
  * @private
  */
 var _isInit = false; // to avoid 'rebinds'

 /**
  * Request
  * @type String
  * @private
  */
 var _request;

 /**
  * Forms Instance
  */
 import Homepage from './Homepage.vue';

 // *****************************
 // ***** Private functions *****
 // *****************************
 /**
  *
  * Forms
  *
  * Create Forms
  *
  */
 var _homepage = function () {
     // Create all requested instances
     new Vue({
         el: '#homepage',
         mixins: [Homepage],
     });
 };

 // ****************************
 // ***** Public functions *****
 // ****************************
 /**
  * start
  *
  * Starts the module
  * Inits private variables and executes specific logic needed for the module
  * to start.
  *
  * @required
  * @param request
  * @type array
  *
  * @public
  */

 self.start = function() {
     if(!_isInit) {
         // Init Forms Component
         _homepage();
     }
 };
```

This is the component that I am trying to mount:

```
<template>
  <div >
      <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Then I added to laravel mix the script file that goes in layouts.homepage blade after compile:**.js('resources/assets/js/homepage/homepage.js', 'public/js/homepage');**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/assets/js/homepage/homepage.js', 'public/js/homepage');
```

After running npm run production the file **public/js/homepage/homepage.js** is created.

EDIT:

I will paste the part of the code that is creating errors in the console:

```
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************

var self = undefined;

var _isInit = false; 

var _homepage = function _homepage() {
  // Create all requested instances
  new Vue({
    el: '#homepage',
    mixins: [_Homepage_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"]]
  });
};
```

The code above generates the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'start' of undefined
at Module../resources/assets/js/homepage/components/homepage.js (homepage.js:12936)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at Object../resources/assets/js/homepage/homepage.js (homepage.js:12974)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at Object.1 (homepage.js:13007)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at homepage.js:84
at homepage.js:87

If I manually replace the **var self = undefined;** to **var self=this** in the **public/js/homepage/homepage.js** file the component is mounted and everything is fixed. the problem is that I have to make this correction everytime after npm run watch. I just don´t understand why this is happening. In the files **assets/js/homepage/homepage.js** and **assets/js/homepage/component/homepage.js** the code is **var self = this**. I dont understand why var self becomes undefined after npm run production in the file **public/js/homepage/homepage.js**.

Does anyobody have any idea what might be happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You add your javascript before the element with id `homepage` exists.

The default `index.html` by a Vue app looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>Example App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>
        We're sorry but this app doesn't work properly
        without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.
      </strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

When the scripts are injected, they are put at the end of the body tag:

```html
<!-- ... -->
    <div id=app></div>
    <script src=js/chunk-vendors.feedbeef.js></script>
    <script src=js/app.baadf00d.js></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should try adding your scripts last and debugging from there:

```php
@extends('lib.master.main')

@section('styles')
@stop

@section('title')
    - Homepage
@stop

@section('content')
    <div id="homepage"></div>
@stop

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{!! asset('js/homepage/homepage.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
@stop
```

Comment: thank you for your response! It was very helpful! I realized that my main blade file was missing the @yield('scripts'). Now at least there is an error showing up in console https://gyazo.com/654285dd4d18bc361bfa603a3ecf3c8c regarding this section of code: https://gyazo.com/680d7e0e9f7f89636884afc93f755594

Comment: Okay so `self` does not exist. Is that some custom code? Please update your original question with this code. It is very unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with code details and more information.

Comment: Okay I see your updated code now. You can trust the generated code to work, you are missing something else probably. Why can't you use the `app.js` directly? I think it would be better suited for customization.

Comment: Thank you, I´m planning on starting over with a different and simpler approach.